# npm view @progress/kendo-angular-grid versions

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I am trying to implement Telerik Kendo UI Grid.
However on typing this command: npm view @progress/kendo-angular-grid versions, I am getting errors as in the attached screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAFcW.jpg)

Comment: Did you get a trial or commercial license?

Answer (score 0):

Kendo Grid and Scheduler are no longer free. They are part of the commercial version
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/core-faq